# Odds of winning a video game combat

Tags: probability

We have a combat between 2 characters in a video game.

Character 1 has starting hit points = 'c1_hit_points'

Character 2 has starting hit points = 'c2_hit_points'

Every turn character 1 deals a random number between 0 and 'c1_damage' of damage to character 2

Then character 2 deals a random number between 0 and 'c2_damage' of damage to character 1

The combat ends when one of them has no hp left.

Can you find a formula to calculate the odds of winning for both characters?

A simulation won't do.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: For clarification, does C1 always get the first hit and only if C2 survives then C2 gets the chance to attack?  Or can C1 and C2 both deal lethal damage simultaneously resulting in a double-ko?  The end result for this will be that this can be modeled as a [markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).  Doing so will be incredibly tedious however, so I would suggest programming a script to run the calculations.

Comment: There is no formula, but you can write a computer program to compute this. The computational complexity is $O(h_1\times h_2\times \max(d_1,d_2))$, where $h_i$ is the health and $d_i$ is the damage. Is this something you would be interested in?